# Issue with multiwebsite with multistore ___store appending twice in magento2.2

Tags: magento2.2, luma-theme

I have multiwebsite with multistore

website1 English, website1 French

website2 English, website2 French 
[image]

I use two theme One for website1 luma and another for website2

**Website1 issue** Luma theme

It switching quite fine with website1 to English and French. but has a append issue when is switch from french and then again to English I have the url as

> website1.com?___store=main_website_view_french?___store=main_website_view_english
>   [image]

**Website2 issue**

The switching  is not working and on inspecting the action it shows the website1 url but with website2 store code.
[image]

when On change the action url to website2 it not switching too that is b2c to b2b.

I have the index file as

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
     case 'Website1.com': 
        $mageRunCode = 'wholesale_website'; 
        $mageRunType = 'website'; 
        break;
     case 'Website2.com': 
        $mageRunCode = 'base';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
        break; 
    }
```

Do I need to make any other changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 
Website2 issue

The switching is not working and on inspecting the action it shows the website1 url but with website2 store code.

Need to change Base url in admin.